# DateTime in .NET Core is Inconsistent

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core, time

My problem is that I do not understand how DateTime works in C# when it comes to time zones.

I know there is a DateTimeKind.

I know that there is an offset.

I see that these do not always agree, and this confuses me greatly.

*My results are on my local PC in the `Central Standard Time` zone, around 3:20 in the afternoon*

When I type:

`DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d H:mm:ss z K")`

It gives me:

`"4/22 15:21:22 -5 -05:00"`

Here, the offset and "DateTimeKind" are in agreement, but I am already confused: is DateTimeKind = Local, or -05:00? Is the -05:00 stored in the POCO object, or looked up on the PC on the fly?

Now let's get really confused; try either of these 2:

`DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("M/d H:mm:ss z K")`
`DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("M/d H:mm:ss z K")`

Both give something like

`"4/22 20:21:49 -5 Z"`

I see it shifted the hour correctly, but the `z` formatter (offset) is wrong - it says `-5` when I would expect it to say `0`.

> It seems like UtcNow, and `ToUniversalTime()` both ignore/don't change the `-5` offset from my time zone.

I am using EF Core, and have several models with timestamp properties - decorated with `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]`, and with default SQL values of `getdate()`.  In my local, Central Time environment, my SQL statement:

```
SELECT [Timestamp], FORMAT([Timestamp], 'zzz') AS 'zzz'
FROM [dbo].[EventTriggers]
```

returns the correct offsets:

```
Timestamp   zzz
2021-04-19 16:53:40.1000000 -05:00
```

Ok, good.

Logs:

In the local environment, these POCO values are printed out with `.ToString("MM/dd hh:mm:ss t z K")`, as:

```
04/19 04:53:40 P -5
```

The hour and offset are correct, and DateTimeKind is blank, which I guess means `Unspecified` - which is fine.

A major major problem happens here though: when I call `ToUniversalTime()` on this value, I get

```
04/19 09:53:40 P +0 Z
```

Remember above, when I wrote:

> It seems like UtcNow, and `ToUniversalTime()` both ignore/don't change the `-5` offset from my time zone.

Well, now it does.  Why?

Comment: Dates and times are hard (that's not a joke, Jon Skeet is really the only qualified expert on it and he still doesn't like it). Can you use `DateTimeOffset` to sort of sidestep the problem?

Comment: DateTimes are pretty stupid.  If you have a DateTime, it can represent the time in UTC or the time in Local, but it doesn't really know that, you need to know that.  When you create a DateTime, you get to decide what kind it is.  There's a DateTimeOffset type (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset) that is only slightly less stupid.  If you really want to work with time zones, you probably want to investigate _NodaTime_ (https://nodatime.org/) - that's the result of Jon Skeet understanding something about all this and helping us all along

Comment: It's important to understand that offsets are not time zones. NodaTime gets that right. It has `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`. The former has just an offset and you can't tell which time zone it's in while the latter has a time zone with all its rules and can apply the right offset at any point in the year.

Comment: Only if you promise that EF Core can reliably bind `DateTimeOffset` with `[DATETIME2](7)` in SQL, regardless of what timezone the SQL DB, the .NET Core service, or the viewer is in, OR which of these 3 generated the timestamp.  Maybe NodaTime is the way to go.

Comment: @madreflection - Right, that's helpful, and makes absolute sense.  Would the "Zone" information need to be persisted/loaded differently in SQL? Like, into/from a second column?  Or could it safely do this with the offset in the SQL `[DATETIME2](7)` data type? Or does `[DATETIME2](7)` have a way to indicate zone?

Comment: If you're storing the date/time value in anything other than UTC, then yes, it would need a coordinated column with that information. You could store the IANA time zone ID in the row, e.g. `'America/New_York'`, or ideally, keep a table with all the IANA time zones and store a reference to it.

Comment: I believe EF Core reads `datetime2(7)` to `DateTime` as `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. There's a way to make it use `DateTimeKind.Utc` but it only works when selecting mapped entities, not custom projections (anonymous types, unmapped types, etc.), IIRC.

Comment: I don't think dates and times are hard or stupid - the technology has been written to be unusable. 
The concept of "Local" time is a problem - it is useless, ambiguous, and harmful due to the confusion and inconsistencies which it causes.
.NET DateTime and NodaTime are BOTH based on this harmful concept.
I am now forced to test 2-way binding between browsers, services, and SQL - in my Central Time local environment, and UTC Azure environment.
That is 8 tests.
A 10 year old could have modeled a better API.I can't tell if this was done out of stupidity, or a resource control strategy.